# How to Zoom in and out in Android?

Tags: android, zooming

Basically, I have this image which is controlled by the remote server. What I want to do is to add a simple Zoom In and Zoom Out function on my magnifier image. Is there any way I can accomplish this? Please help me, I have struggling for a day trying to figure out the solution for this, so please help me I would really appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is old, but take a look at http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/: it includes pinch-to-zoom `View` implementations that you may be able to use.